# if statement within function breaks javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, highslide

I'm stumped with this one and would really appreciate someone's help.

I'm customizing highslide for integration with wordpress. Via the following code within the highslide.config.js file I'm adding a class name to certain elements and passing different attributes through an onClick call depending on certain conditions.

Everything works until I add the following code:

```js
if(hsGroupByWpGallery){
    slideshowGroup: this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id
};
```

When the above code is present, not only does that one statement not execute, but the whole thing stops working. Even if the if statement is something like if(1=1){}; it still breaks.

If I have instead simply slideshowGroup: this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id or nothing (the two options I'm looking for), both do what I would expect. I just need an if statement to switch between them.

Here's the relevant code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  
  var hsCustomGalleryGroupClass = 'fbbHighslide_GalleryGroup';
  var hsCustomGalleryGroupChecker = 0;
  var hsGroupByWpGallery = true;


    jQuery('.' + hsCustomGalleryGroupClass).each(function(){
        hsCustomGalleryGroupChecker++;
        return false;
    });
    if (hsCustomGalleryGroupChecker > 0){
        jQuery('.' + hsCustomGalleryGroupClass).each(function(i, $item) {
            var grpID = $item.id;
            jQuery('#' + grpID + ' .gallery-item a').addClass('highslide').each(function() {
                this.onclick = function() {
                    return hs.expand(this, {
                        slideshowGroup: grpID
                    });
                };
            });
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('.gallery-item a').addClass('highslide').each(function() {
            this.onclick = function() {
                return hs.expand(this, {
                    // This is the problem if statement
                    if(hsGroupByWpGallery){
                      slideshowGroup: this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id
                    };
                });
            };
        });
    };
  
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the code you added won't parse... it's invalid syntax. that `:` should be an `=` or something.  i'm not sure what the goal is here.

Comment: Did you mean `slideshowGroup = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id`

Comment: What is slideshowGroup? You cannot assign a variable with a ':' this type of assignment is used inside object literal e.g., {key: valye}

Comment: ohh.... so based on the other code... you didn't copy your `{ brackets }` or the function it's passed to... or return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to assign a conditional property.. you can't have a `if` condition inside a object definition like that

```
jQuery('.gallery-item a').addClass('highslide').each(function () {
    this.onclick = function () {
        var obj = {};
        //assign the property only if the condition is tru
        if (hsGroupByWpGallery) {
            obj.slideshowGroup = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
        }
        return hs.expand(this, obj);
    };
});
```

---

Another way to do the same is

```
jQuery('.gallery-item a').addClass('highslide').each(function () {
    this.onclick = function () {
        //if the flag is true sent an object with the property else an empty object
        return hs.expand(this, hsGroupByWpGallery ? {
            slideshowGroup: this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id
        } : {});
    };
});
```

Comment: Well, both of those work. Thank you!

I'm not entirely sure of how the first one is working though. By declaring the var obj = {}; it appears that you are creating an object, then later in the if statement you seem to be adding an attribute (slideshowGroup) along with a value for it. Assuming that that's right, the part that has me confused is that you then pass the entire object as a parameter of the hs.expand, when I think what it's looking for is simply the value of obj.slideshow. How is the correct data getting extracted from the obj object?

Comment: Also (since we're restricted on characters here):

Your second option is the shorthand if statement, right? I would have thought that that would be subject to the same problem as a standard if statement. Can you explain why this works while a regular if statement does not?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want this, based on the other code:

```
   jQuery('.gallery-item a').addClass('highslide').each(function() {
      this.onclick = function() {

         if(hsGroupByWpGallery){
            return hs.expand(this, {
               slideshowGroup: this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id
            });
          }
       };
   });
```